# Android: InputConnection is missing a getSelection() method

Tags: android, inputconnection

Why do I have a `setSelection` in [`InputConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#setSelection%28int,%20int%29), but not a `getSelection()`?

Should I just do a `getTextBeforeCursor(VERY_HIGH_NUMBER, 0)` and calculate the `.length()` of that string?

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it's silly that `getSelection()` doesn't exist.  Your solution works ok but you have to assume that there's just a cursor showing and not a whole selected range of text.  I haven't yet figured out how to fill that hole.

**EDIT:**  Oh, of course:

```
int selStart = ic.getTextBeforeCursor(HIGH_NUMBER, 0).length();
String sel = ic.getSelectedText(); 
int selEnd = selStart + (sel==null? 0: sel.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [InputMethodService.onUpdateSelection (int oldSelStart, int oldSelEnd, int newSelStart, int newSelEnd, int candidatesStart, int candidatesEnd)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateSelection%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I wanted to refactor out references to my `EditText` and use the `InputConnection` only. To get the selection start and end, I ended up using `getExtractedText(…)` method like so:

```
    private static final ExtractedTextRequest request = new ExtractedTextRequest();
    private InputConnection ic;

// …

    ExtractedText extractedText = ic.getExtractedText(request, 0);
    int start = extractedText.selectionStart;
    int end = extractedText.selectionEnd;
```